# Exception Handling for an Array

Tags: java, arrays

I'm printing out an array of entry's for a phone book. However if an object has been deleted, I would like to print a message saying object is no longer there, but then carry on printing out the rest of the array. At the moment I get the message saying Missing Entry, but it stops and doesn't print out the rest of the array. Is it possible?

```
public class Entry {

String surname;
String initial;
String number;


public Entry(String surname, String initial, String number) {
    this.surname = surname;
    this.initial = initial;
    this.number = number;
}

public String getSurname(){
    return surname;
}

public String getInitial(){
    return initial;
}

public String getNumber() {
    return number;
}

void setNumber(String number){
    this.number = number;
}

public String toString(){
    return surname+ "\t " +initial+ "\t" +number;
}
}



import java.util.Arrays;

public class ArrayDirectory implements Directory{


int DIRECTORY_SIZE = 6; 
Entry [] directory = new Entry[DIRECTORY_SIZE];
int numberOfElements = 0;


public void addEntry(String surname, String initial, String num) {

    int i = findFreeLocation();     
    directory[i] = new Entry(surname, initial, num);
    numberOfElements++;
}


public void deleteEntry(String surname, String initial){
    // TODO delete entry via name
//  if ()
    int i = findEntryIndex(surname, initial);                     
    directory[i] = null;
    numberOfElements--;
}


public void print() throws EntryNotFoundException{

    for(int i = 0 ; i < DIRECTORY_SIZE ; i++){

        if(directory[i] != null){

            System.out.println(directory[i].toString());
        }
        else{
            throw new EntryNotFoundException("Entry Missing");
        }
    }
}

private int findEntryIndex(String surname, String initial) {
    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < DIRECTORY_SIZE; i++) 
    {
        if(directory[i] != null && directory[i].getSurname().equals(surname) && directory[i].getInitial().equals(initial))
        { 
            break;
        }
    }
    return i;
}



private int findEntryIndex(String number) {

    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < DIRECTORY_SIZE; i++) // private method to find index of an Entry within the array directory
    {
        if(directory[i] != null && directory[i].getNumber().equals(number))
        { 
            break;
        }
    }

    return i;
}


private int findFreeLocation() {

    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < DIRECTORY_SIZE; i++) 
    {           
        if(directory[i] == null)
        { 
            break;
        }
    }
    return i;
}
}
```

Comment: why do you throw an exception if you don't want to interrupt your loop ? is this your code?

Comment: Handle the exception in the method itself. Do not throw it. If you throw it then handle it there.

Comment: If an entry not being present in the array is a valid data scenario, then there's nothing really that exceptional about it. In that case, throwing an exception is not the appropriate thing to be doing.

Comment: Return -1 from all the methods if it fails. By default its returning you DIRECTORY_SIZE that will create a problem.

Comment: @Braj this isn't C we're talking about ;-P void is acceptable return types.

Comment: Look at method findEntryIndex,findFreeLocation,findEntryIndex

Answer (score 0):

You need to `catch` the exception instead of allowing it to `throw` itself to the caller.

Something like:

```
try {

    // do something that may throw an exception

} catch (TheSpecificExceptionYouExpect e) {
    // either handle the exception, log it, print it, or ignore it.
    // here's how to print it
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Then your program will continue as normal. When your `throw` an exception, the control gets returned to the `caller` immediately, stopping your method's execution.

Comment: @JohnSetter no worries. From your profile it looks like you are teaching yourself Java. Kudos to you (I <3 Java!), it will be very rewarding in the end. The `try/catch` block is not unique to Java, many languages have it, or something similar. You use `try/catch` blocks anytime you are about to attempt some "risky" code. :)

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, the very definition of an exception being thrown is to interrupt the entire call stack up to the point that the exception is handled. This means that unless you handle your exception **inside** the for loop itself (or don't throw an exception, just behave differently), you will not be able to continue printing anything after your exception is thrown. Just change your code to not throw an exception, and just print something different out to indicate a failure:

```
public void print() throws EntryNotFoundException{

    for(int i = 0 ; i < DIRECTORY_SIZE ; i++){

        if(directory[i] != null){

            System.out.println(directory[i].toString());
        }
        else{
            //this breaks up to the point it is handled,
            //and we can't continue in the loop at the same
            //point this was thrown later in code
            //throw new EntryNotFoundException("Entry Missing");

            //Just print out a different response
            System.out.println("Entry Missing");
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There's no need to throw an exception here, you said yourself you want to print "Missing Entry" and continue. That's standard code flow:

```
public void print() {
    for(int i = 0 ; i < DIRECTORY_SIZE ; i++) {
        if(directory[i] != null){
            System.out.println(directory[i].toString());
        }
        else{
            System.out.println("Missing Entry: #"+i);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As soon as you throw the exception it's going to leave the method. Do something like LOG the missing elements and IF something was missing then maybe throw an exception after everything is complete. Then it prints everything and you'll see what elements are missing.

Actually don't make print a void and just return a status =) Basically don't abuse exceptions unless this is a learning exercise..and btw Exceptions can be costly!